# How to determine a stored procedure name in Azure Datawarehouse?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm migrating a SQL Server database to Azure parallel data warehouse, and I'm having an issue with adapting the stored procedures to Azures limitations.

Part of the procedures is logging to a log table, which includes the use of
`OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` to identify the logging procedure.

Unfortunately, this option is not supported in the new environment.

Do you know of any alternatives for telling which stored procedure is currently running without hard coding it?

Comment: I think you are out of luck

Comment: try adding this to beginning of stored proc and see if it helps:`select object_name(objectid) from sys.dm_Exec_requests ec
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.sql_handle)
where session_id=@@spid`